# How to make VS code able to lookup code in subproject directory for autocompletion?

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I have project structure

```
-core_data
-core_domain
-core_ui
-core_launcher
```

The dependency of these 4 projects is

```
core_launcher -> core_ui -> core_domain -> core_data
```

4 projects are located in the same directory and I include one to another via pubspec.yaml file (for example core_launcher/pubspec.yaml):

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  core_ui:
    path: ../core_ui
```

The same thing I do with all projects to make dependency hierarchy.

The problem is that I can import all files from `core_ui` subproject when I'm currently editing some file in `core_launcher` but VSCode doesn't see any classes from his parents
(core_domain & core_data).

However, I can input `import 'blah-blah-blah` manually and VSCode see this class and import works well, but I can't do that with hit Alt+Enter that I do for fast-import.
So, I'm wondering why autocomplete is not working for inherited libraries.

Somebody had the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

Code completion will only show classes from your *direct* dependencies. There are two possible reasons for this:

1. Relying on transitive dependencies is not a good idea, because it's possible that your dependencies will remove or change their dependencies and not consider that a breaking change.
2. If code completion listed all classes from *all transitive dependencies* the code completion list would be *huge* and include classes from packages you do not recognise (because they are just other packages dependencies). This would be a bad user experience and make it easy to accidentally rely on packages that are not listed in your `pubspec.yaml`.

The fix is to explicitly list `core_domain` and `core_data` in your `pubspec.yaml` too, because if your project is using classes from them, then they are dependencies.